# Constant button linking to a page throughout the app

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a button at the top right of every page that I want to link to a certain page within my application. Is there a way to give each instance of this button the same behaviour? and if so where would the code sit so that it affects every page? Many thanks in advance.

View:

```
items: [
            {
    title: '<span class="logo"></span>',
                            xtype: 'titlebar',
                            docked: 'top',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    align: 'right',
                                    iconAlign: 'right',
                                    id: 'buytickets',
                                    text: 'Buy Tickets'
                                }
                            ]
             }
]
```

Controller (specific to one page):

```
config: {
    refs: {
        main: 'ListNav'
    },
    control: {
        "button#buytickets": {
            tap: 'buytickets'
        }
    }
},

buytickets: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'buyticketspanel'
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just put the button at the top of your Viewport, in the app.js file:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    requires: [],    
    views: [/*Views*/],    
    controllers: [/*Controllers*/],

    viewport: {
        layout: 'vbox'
    },

    launch: function() {
        var me = this;

        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add([
            {
                title: '<span class="logo"/>',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        align: 'right',
                        iconAlign: 'right',
                        id: 'buytickets',
                        text: 'Buy Tickets',
                        handler: me.doBuyTickets
                    }
                ]
            },
            Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main', {flex: 1})
        ]);
    },

    doBuyTickets: function() {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

******EDIT******:

However, you won't be able to re-purpose that bar as the title bar for a `NestedView`.  If you need to have that, then you might be best served with a utils file that has a method to add a button to a toolbar, and just reuse that in the init function of any `NestedView` components.

Utils.js:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.util.Utils", {
    singleton: true,
    addBuyButton: function(toolbar)
    {
        toolbar.add({
            text: 'Buy Tickets',
            align: 'right',
            handler: function() {
                //do stuff
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            nestedList: 'nestedlist'
        },
        control: {
            app-page: {
                initialize: 'initAppPage'
            }
        }
    },

    initAppPage: function()
    {
        MyApp.utils.addBuyButton(this.getNestedList().getNavigationBar());
    }
});
```

Comment: ok. and would adding this override items like the default titlebar with back button when you push a page on to the stack? as keeping that functionality is essential for me. Thanks for the help.